# Possible to create a stored procedure which loops through another and unions?

Tags: t-sql

I have a procedure in a 3rd party database called GetDocumentHistory. This procedure returns all kind of information about a document and it's history. This procedure accepts DocumentId as the parameter - and does all kinds of internal business logic. When this executes I get everything I need back.

What I need to do is pass this procedure a DocumentId, but I have many DocumentIds I need to run it for.

I am looking to write my own procedure which accepts OwnerId, which I find all the DocumentIds associated with that owner, and call the GetDocumentHistory procedure individually for each DocumentId I found. I would then like the results of all executions of the GetDocumentHistory procedure to be returned from my procedure in one big resultset.

The GetDocumentHistory procedure cannot be easily modified to return all of these records, and it's not a simple SELECT in there but lots of loading variables and doing things with them.

Is this possible to loop and union the results?

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: This is too vague for us to be any help, but you'll likely to get better performance by incorporating the logic of the stored procedure in the new one rather than look at combining result sets (assuming it's possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `insert ... exec`.  It does require you to specify exactly what the stored procedure returns.  Here's an example:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetDocumentHistory') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.GetDocumentHistory
go
create procedure dbo.GetDocumentHistory(
    @DocumentId int)
as
    select  'Ghost Writer' as Author
    ,       @DocumentId as Number
go
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetMultiDocHistory') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.GetMultiDocHistory
go
create procedure dbo.GetMultiDocHistory(
    @a int
,   @b int)
as begin
    declare @t table (name varchar(50), number int)

    declare @i int
    set @i = @a
    while @i <= @b
        begin
        insert @t exec dbo.GetDocumentHistory @i
        set @i = @i + 1
        end

    select name, number from @t
end
go
exec dbo.GetMultiDocHistory 1, 3
```

This prints:

```
name             number
Ghost Writer     1
Ghost Writer     2
Ghost Writer     3
```